# Text file keeps deleting contents on the file. How do i get around this?

Tags: java, input, output, java.util.scanner, java-io

Code showing the array:

```js
int i = 0;
            
            try {
            
               File fl = new File("Product List.txt");
               
               Scanner scn = new Scanner(fl);
            
               while(scn.hasNext()) {
               
                  String productName = scn.next();
               
                  double productPrice = scn.nextDouble();
               
                  int productAmount = scn.nextInt();
               
                  product[i] = new Products(productName,productPrice,productAmount);
               
                  i = i + 1;
               
               }
            
            }
            
            catch(IOException exc) {
            
            }
//and this code to update contents

try{
         
            Formatter writer = new Formatter("Product List.txt");
            
            for(int i = 0;i < productList.length;++i) {
            
               prd.setQuantity(prd.getQuantity() - 1);
               
               writer.format(prd.getProductName(),prd.getPrice(),prd.getQuantity(),"\n");
            
            }
         
            writer.close();
         
         }
         
         catch(IOException exc){
         
         }
```

Every time i run the program, it keeps deleting the contents and by the time i reach the part where i have to update the contents of the file, the file is empty.

How do i fix this runtime error?

Comment: You really should not silently ignore Exceptions. I would bet that if you did an exc.printStackTrace(); in your catch clause you would learn what the problem is.

Comment: i will try that thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From javadoc:

> public Formatter(String fileName)
>             throws FileNotFoundException Constructs a new formatter with the specified file name. The charset used is the default charset for
>   this instance of the Java virtual machine.
>
> The locale used is the default locale for this instance of the Java
>   virtual machine.
>
> Parameters: fileName - The name of the file to use as the destination
>   of this formatter. **If the file exists then it will be truncated to
>   zero size**; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be
>   written to the file and is buffered.

So I think you should load all content of the file to a stringbuilder, append next content and write it down.